# writeClipboard for matrices or data frames?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, clipboard

[`writeClipboard`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/writeClipboard) works for raw or character vectors. Is there anything that can let me place matrices/data.frames into the clipboard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think `write.table` with the `file = "clipboard"` argument will work.  Here's an example:

```
write.table(mtcars, "clipboard", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: just like `writeClipboard`, this works only on a windows machine. Try it on a mac and it will explode. Then you would need to do something like clip <- pipe("pbcopy", "w")
write.table(mtcars, file=clip, sep="\t", col.names=NA)
close(clip)

Comment: As Chris mentions below, this method can be a problem for larger tables. Reading the write.table and then file help files, the clipboard is an internal storage with a 32 Kb limit. If your table exceeds this, you get an error.

Fortunately you can increase the size of the internal storage by replacing "clipboard" with "clipboard-128" to give 128 Kb storage, or whatever you need, e.g.
write.table(mtcars, "clipboard-128", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)

Answer (score 10):

A nice OS independent solution is:

```
library(clipr)
clipr::write_clip(mtcars)
```

But may suffer from size limitations as well.

Comment: Doesn't suffer as bad write.table evidently. Thank you for this life saver +1.

Answer (score 4):

The above is mostly a wrong answer if your table is a little bigger.

```
Warning message:
In .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  :
  clipboard buffer is full and output lost
```

The hack fix is this:

```
writeClipboard(knitr::kable(d))
```